# How to convert XML array text items into numbers in ColdFusion?

Tags: arrays, xml, coldfusion

I am having problems converting XML data into the appropriate data types using a function.
I have read in an XML file using XmlParse().
Within that there is an array which I loop around. `<Cfloop array=#i.Task# index="t">`
My understanding is that the items in this array are XML text. I can display all the items with CFoutput no problem. One item in the array (BaseLineColor) is a colour. `#t.BaseLineColor#` However this colour value is a single decimal integer number of varying length. I have worked out the maths to convert this decimal number into R,G,B decimal values. All good so far.
The problem is that if I try mathematical functions on BaseLineColor, then I get:

> The value ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? BaseLineColor 255 /BaseLineColor  cannot be converted to a number.

So OK I have tried a few methods to try and convert BaseLineColor to an integer but nothing works. Val() doesn't work. In fact I can't seem to convert it into any datatype.
For example, here is me trying to make it a string - same error:

```
 <cfscript>
            Strbaselinecolor=toString(t.BaseLineColor);
            rdec=floor(Strbaselinecolor / 65536);
            gdec=floor((Srtbaselinecolor - rdec * 65536)/256);
            bdec=floor(Strbaselinecolor - rdec * 65536 - gdec * 256);
            writeOutput("#t.baselinecolor#: #Strbaselinecolor# red #rdec#, green #gdec#, blue #bdec#")
</cfscript>
```

What function should I be using? Am I supposed to be pre-processing the XML in some way before I can refer to some of these values as integers?

There are a lot of values in the XML data which are numbers (some integers and some floating point numbers) and so it is not just about these items that are colours but a more general problem with using any XML data that is not text. I have tried to find some reference material on this but have not found anything relevant so far. Yet I'm guessing this is a common issue when reading in XML files.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you tell us what you get when you dump `t.BaseLineColor`?  I am curious why the generated error contains the xml version header text.  `writeDump(t.BaseLineColor);`

Comment: The errors are likely because you're trying to perform math functions on an xml node, which is a complex object. WriteDump `toString(t.BaseLineColor)` and you'll see it's an xml string - not the number 255.  You want the node's text, which is a simple value. Try `t.xmlText` instead.

Comment: Correction: try `t.BaseLineColor.xmlText` instead

Comment: I with question had an example of the XML data.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is correct. The code is trying perform mathematical operations on something that is not a number, despite the fact that it may *appear* to be one in a browser... You're probably getting tripped up by how browsers handle tag based code like xml.

This code (incorrectly) shows the value of `t.BaseLineColor` as a simple number `255`

```
<cfscript>
    t = xmlParse('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><BaseLineColor>255</BaseLineColor>');
    writeOutput(t.BaseLineColor);
</cfscript>
```

[Runnable Example](https://trycf.com/gist/c72791ba823796e89bc06dd542bdf36b/acf2016?theme=monokai)

However, using a browser's "Inspect Element" tool, reveals the value is actually an xml string. Since browsers treat anything enclosed in `<` and `>` as html tags, which aren't rendered, only the number `255` is visible on screen.

[image: Inspect Element Result]

[writeDump()](https://cfdocs.org/writedump) is more helpful here. It shows `t.BaseLineColor` as an xml node, and it's value is accessible through the `xmlText` attribute.

[image: WriteDump of XML Node]

That simple value *can* be used in mathematical operations.

```
<cfscript>
    t = xmlParse('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><BaseLineColor>255</BaseLineColor>');
    result = t.BaseLineColor.xmlText  / 65536 ;
    writeOutput( result );
</cfscript>
```

[Runnable Example](https://trycf.com/gist/ddd6c7fd49854752c87ee054780ce75c/acf2016?theme=monokai)